# Using React + D3 drag

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I couldn't find a single example but this,

D3-Drag: https://github.com/d3/d3-drag

I want to use for example custom SVG, and be able to drag it with React

I found this example to use only SVG:
https://medium.com/@jeffbutsch/using-d3-in-react-with-hooks-4a6c61f1d102

that make a new component using D3, so in the end once I write in my App.js: `<MyD3Component data={[1,2,3]}/>` it converts these numbers to `<text>1</text>`, `<text>2</text>`, `<text>3</text>`

But I want each text to be draggable,
How can it be done?

Comment: https://dev.to/taowen/make-react-svg-component-draggable-2kc check this out, it helped me